# emulate input for dos application

Tags: c#, batch-file

i have to input some data into an really old dos application and wanted to automate this. first i tried SendKeys, which failed, after that i tried the InputSimulator (inputsimulator.codeplex.com) which failed too. It works in any other Application (even cmd...) but not in the application i want to...

sample code i used:

```
InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("test");
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.F1);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.F1);
```

i also tried it with SimulateKeyPress, same results :(
can someone please give me some hints?

Target System: Win XP

Screen of the app:
http://images.devs-on.net/Image/wxhZouyZdwemgTRp-Bereich.png

EDIT1: is it possible to start the .bat from my application and stdin the input?

EDIT2: as Boluc Papuccuoglu pointed out the stdin approach won't work. so is there anyway to code a working keystrokes emulating function?

EDIT3: with keybd_event i got it to write to the application. BUT... i tried it with

```
public const int A = 0x41;
public const int C = 0x43;

keybd_event(A, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(A, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
keybd_event(C, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(C, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

but i only get 2 times "a".

EDIT4: doesn't matter which Virtual Key i give to keybd_event, he is always writing "a" and nothing else. seems like i have to do it the old fashioned aka manual way.

EDIT5: so yeah, manual entry sucked, so i decided to give autoit a try and it works. WTF? maybe someone can explain me how autoits way of sending keys to a program is different then sendkeys, inputsimulator and keybd_event.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the stdin approach probably will not work. From what I can see in the screenshot, the application most probably acts on keypresses, not the contents of the input stream.

Comment: if using external utilities is ok, AutoIT or AutoHotKey can emulate keyboard typing.